# What are differences between POP access and mail forwarding?

Tags: email, pop3

This is the situation: I have a mail account in a domain i bought (say example.com) and I want to manage it from my old gmail id itself. I have setup it such that I can send as that user from gmail itself using SMTP (smtp.example.com).

My dilemma is whether to use POP access to fetch the mail to my gmail id (configure in Gmail) or to setup my domain account to forward all mails to my gmail inbox. What are pros and cons in each approach? (I wanted to avoid POP since it is slower whereas forwarding will work instantaneously.)

Comment: some mail services when they forward, they don't forward a copy. So it is moving, which isn't as good.Forwarding is less hassle to set up.No need to enter a server and port and user/pass.  Forwarding happens straight away so you get the forwarded email with the rest. If it forwards a copy then I prefer forwarding. If it just moves it,then maybe often there i'd prefer POP 'cos at least it keeps the email at the source.Forwarding can offer good filters at source since the work is done at source. You could add at dest with the rest.If POP filters would only be at destination only after "popping"

Comment: My doubt was about how the mail would be handled. Will the other party know that the mail is being forwarded and replied from some other mail id? In POP this cannot happen. (note that I use SMPT from Gmail to reply; not on-behalf sending.)

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding is faster and uses no passwords.